# Window.ethereum undefined on tab with local webpage

Tags: metamask, javascript

I have the metamask extension. When I do typeof(window.ethereum) in the console for a chrome tab, I get the type as object. However if I open mywebpage.html in a tab, which is just a heading around:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> document.write(typeof(window.ethereum)); </script>
```

then this typeof is 'undefined', either on the page or on the console.

I want to write a webpage that accesses metamask, how do I do that?

Comment: How do you serve the html page? directly from the filesystem or through a web server. Which address are you using? localhost, or the lan IP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Create a simple html page like and store in a file named **scratch.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Using web3 API with MetaMask</title>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@1.2.2/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            window.addEventListener('load', function () {
                if (window.ethereum) {
                    window.web3 = new Web3(ethereum);
                    ethereum.enable()
                        .then(() => {
                            console.log("Ethereum enabled");
    
                            web3.eth.getAccounts(function (err, acc) {
                                if (err != null) {
                                    self.setStatus("There was an error fetching your accounts");
                                    return;
                                }
                                if (acc.length > 0) {
                                    console.log(acc);
                                }
                            });
                        })
                        .catch(() => {
                            console.warn('User didn\'t allow access to accounts.');
                            waitLogin();
                        });
                } else {
                    console.log("Non-Ethereum browser detected. You should consider installing MetaMask.");
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    </html>
```

2. Run the page with a web server:

```
    $ python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

*This step is important for metamask (don't open just the html file)*

3. Open your browser enter http://localhost:8000/scratch.html and connect metamask to your page. Look into the console window of your browser and you should find the current account of Metamask. Expected console output:

```
Ethereum enabled                                  scratch.html:18 
["<your first account number in Metamask>"]       scratch.html:26
```

Comment: thanks! I didn't know I needed to use a server, and I used visual studio Live Server instead of python

Comment: Quick tip to save time, the python server should be run in the same directory as the html for it to be accessible on the server