# window.ethereum undefined even on localhost

Tags: metamask

I have metamask installed. When I type `window.ethereum` in the console in a random webpage, I get a Proxy object.

When I type `window.ethereum` in my locally served webpage on `localhost:5000`, I get `undefined`. The page is served using `python -m http.server 5000`?

How can I get metamask to inject `window.ethereum` on my local website? When searching for this issue, all solutions suggest running my page with a server, but this is already what I am doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a mistake in the html file. I wrote `<!DOCTYPE>` instead of `<!DOCTYPE> html>`. It seems like `window.ethereum` is not injected when in Quirks mode.

Answer (score 1):

This question is repeated.

Run the page with a web server:
`$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000`

check this post: [Window.ethereum undefined on tab with local webpage](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/94021/window-ethereum-undefined-on-tab-with-local-webpage)

Hope this works
Let me know if you still face the same problem.

Comment: You did not read the question.

Comment: Don't worry, the moderator who closed the question did not read the question either!